# SQL table Merge two tables into new table?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

This is Japanese Characters. 
This database is Very Large is.
I am using SQL, MVC.

1. K_KEB table is 170000 row (i have)
2. CHARACTER table is 13000 table (i have)
3. NEW_TABLE table is ????

How to Create (NEW_TABLE) table. Please Help me

[image]

MVC , SQL server

Comment: ???!!! what's your question?

Comment: I have Two table (K_KEB, CHARACTER)
HOW TO CREATE (NEW_TABLE) table?

Comment: Are the two table related to each other, for example via primary key? Or what you want to do with the new table?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Htoy6.png

Comment: I think i understand what do you mean now. are you using code first?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's not clear which approach are you following. is it `code-first` or `model-first`.

If it's `code-first` then you you can do one of the two suggestions below:

1- Follow `EF convention` and create the the relationship between the
    two tables.
 2- Configure Many-to-Many relationship using `Fluent API`.

Check this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) for more info.